# Nextjs 10.0 builds without styles

Tags: next.js

Hello guys can anybody help with Nextjs v10 build ? it builds without styles :|
here is my package.json and next.config.js
I import all styles in _app.js, it also comes in chrome network -> preview without styles
On vercel everything is ok, but when i try to build on my computer, it's without styles :|

**
next.config.js
**

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['localhost','assets.vercel.com','via.placeholder.com','mine-front-new.vercel.app'],
  },
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mine",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "prod:build": "SET NODE_ENV=production && next build && next export",
    "export": "next build && next export"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.6",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "next": "10.0.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.9.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-facebook": "^8.1.4",
    "react-lottie": "^1.2.3",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.1",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cookie": "^0.4.0",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react-date-range": "^1.0.3",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.26.1",
    "react-toastify": "^6.0.8",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.15.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure u use appropriate css loaders. I faced the same issue and resolved using this,

```
loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
```

My next.config.js

```
module.exports = withImages({
target: 'serverless',
webpack: function (config, { webpack }) {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(eot|svg|gif|md)$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
    })
    
    return config
  },
})
```